# RflutterAlert : making a button in another line

Tags: flutter, line-breaks, flutter-packages

Hello everyone i have this simple code that contains 3 buttons

```
void _showOptions (bill , context){
    Alert(
      context: context,
      type: AlertType.info,
      style: AlertStyle(titleStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
      title: translator.currentLanguage == 'ar' ? 'الخيارات'
          : 'Options',
      buttons: [
        DialogButton(
          onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    BillView(widget.userInformation , widget.userInformation, bill))
            );
          },
          color: Color(0xffff9900),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(translator.translate("view_bill"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              SizedBox(width: 5,),
              Icon(Icons.featured_play_list , color: Colors.white,)
            ],
          ),
        ),

        DialogButton(
        onPressed: (){
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                    PurchasesEdit(widget.userInformation , widget.userInformation, bill))
            );
          },
          color: Colors.blue,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(translator.translate("edit"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                SizedBox(width: 5,),
                Icon(Icons.edit , color: Colors.white,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        DialogButton(
          onPressed: (){
            return _deleteBill(bill['id'] ,  context);
          },
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(translator.translate("delete"), style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                SizedBox(width: 5,),
                Icon(Icons.delete_forever , color: Colors.white,)
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ],
    ).show();
  }
```

its working fine but the three buttons are next to each other and i want one of them to be at the bottom and the other two to be at the top

the result right now

View -- Edit -- Delete

What i want

Edit -- Delete

----View------

How should i do that ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library uses a [Row](https://github.com/RatelHub/rflutter_alert/blob/2d099a8109ab9fb96f9d1aa72670fa5414118d9b/lib/src/alert.dart#L122) to Render Buttons, so it's impossible to make a

Edit -- Delete

----View------

layout. I don't use that library but you might need to fork the github project, or use only one `DialogButton`  and inside there make your custom button layout in the child property, or add your buttons directly to `content`. There is a lot of workarounds but the main one i would suggest is using [showGeneralDialog](https://www.programmersought.com/article/5464859494/), sure it might take some time to set up, but you can do custom layouts more easily in there

Comment: hmmm i am already working on a custom version of the package locally so i think i will change its base code to fit my needs, Thanks i  was just wondering if there is a built-in way to do it